# Jagged fonts in pdf export

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have been abusing Photoshop and Layer Comps for DTP purposes for some years now, and it has been working remarkably well for me. I setup a Layer Comp per page and then export to PDF.

Every now and then though, Photoshop does not agree, and exports jagged text. The root cause is not always clear. Sometimes it seems related to font decoration, sometimes to context, especially when surrounded by transparency or vector objects. It's always isolated to some text areas, never for everything.

When it happens, this

[image: crisp]

becomes this

[image: jagged]

in the pdf export.

Removing font decoration or surrounding objects can sometimes fix the problem, but that is very limiting of course. Any clues on how or where to look for a proper solution?

### Edit:

I created a blank document with some text boxes in Times New Roman.

For some markup, I applied the bold font.

[image: regular bold]

For other markup, I used faux bold.

[image: faux bold]

When I save as PDF, there is no issue. But when I create a Layer Comp from them and then export Layer Comps to PDF, I get the following behaviour:

[image: font issues]

So, when exporting Layer Comps to PDF, underlining causes jagged text unless the text also contains faux bold.

(Note that even though case 3 doesn't show it, the last word *is* underlined.)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Could it be a bug of some kind? I Perhaps better to contact Adobe tech support, or search their help forum to see if others have had the same problem.

Comment: Well, the whole premise is that it's very hard to figure out what triggers it exactly and that I have not been able to find anything online that looks the same as this problem. Therefore, I was hoping that someone in here would have a pointer. And I totally suspect it to be a bug on the part of Adobe, but agreed, I could try to open a case with them for this.

Comment: Have you checked the PDF across multiple devices and same issue ?

Comment: You get the same issue if you create another blank file, type some text and export to PDF ?

Comment: Have you tried using another font ? It could be a document or font issue, less likely a Photoshop issue/bug.

Comment: I would wager greatly that it's an issue with the font. Font corruption is a sneaky thing... doesn't always create clear, concise, problems or warnings. But when fonts don't act normally, they may be corrupt.

Comment: I am willing to follow the hypothesis of the corrupted font, but that leaves two observations/questions. (1) The repro is on a Mac M1, while I had similar issues on Windows. (2) If my specific font is corrupt, I would expect others to not be able to repro (no one I know tried yet ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (jagged type in PDF export from Photoshop) and I found the answer in another post. Turns out if you use the "faux italics" in Photoshop it seems to always rasterize the type before exporting to PDF. And it does this for the entire text block even if you only italicized a few words. So, choose a specific typeface like Minion semibold italic, DO NOT choose Minion regular and then click on the italic symbol to italicize it. (I don't know if this is true for "faux bold" as well, but that seems logical.) And, I saved my PDF in version 8. Don't know if this matters. Good luck!

Comment: To some extent, that explanation makes sense, but there must be another variable at play as well. In my case, fauxbold is not an issue but underlining is. Moreover: fauxbold makes the issue with underline go away.